# Is there a Standard way to update UI and the DB while thinking about performance?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 ideas :

1. PUT/POST on server to update item, then do a simple setState({ item:
   res.data }) to update the UI.
2. Update the item on the UI with setState and PUT/POST to update the DB in the background.

is the second method better for performance? (save the request/response time since it happens in the background and the user is only concerned with the UI)

Comment: There's no "performance" different between the 2. The setting of the state and the API request are completely unrelated performance wise. The difference is in the feedback and error handling. In the first case, it takes a while to execute, so the user won't get immediate feedback, but if it goes wrong you can indicate as such in as easy way. Users are used to some operations taking a bit of time and potentially failing. The second one lets you update the UI immediately so it feels very snappy, but if the request fails then you're left with an awkward situation UI/UX wise

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is error prone since what would happen if the server fails to update the data? The UI will display the faulty data.